# Denomination of Money using C

Tags: c

I have a problem with my program - I want to hide some of my output.

```
int main(void){

    char redo;
    int money, x[6],y[6],total;

    x[0] = 1000; x[1] = 500; x[2] = 200; x[3] = 100; x[4] = 50; x[5] = 20;

do{

    system("cls");
    printf("Enter your Money: ");
    scanf("%d", &money);
    total = money;

    printf("\nBreakdown:\n");

    for(int i=0;money != 0 && i < 6; i++){

        y[i] = ( money - (money % x[i]) )/x[i];
        money = (money % x[i]);

        printf("%10d  x  %d  =  %5d \n", x[i], y[i], (x[i] * y[i]));

    }

    printf("---------------------------\n");
    printf("Total:                %d",total);

    if(money>0){
       system("cls");
    printf("Invalid Input !");

    }
    getch();

system("cls");
printf("\nEnter y or Y to continue: ");
    scanf(" %c", &redo);

}while((redo == 'y')||(redo== 'Y'));

return 0;
}
```

My output shows:

```
Enter you Money: 9720

Breakdown:

1000 x  9 = 9000
500  x  1 = 500
200  x  1 = 200
100  x  0 = 0
50   x  0 = 0
20   x  1 = 20
----------------
total:     9720
```

I want to hide the labels where result = 0:

```
100  x  0 = 0
50   x  0 = 0
```

I am expecting my output to be like this:

```
Enter you Money: 9720

Breakdown:

1000 x  9 = 9000
500  x  1 = 500
200  x  1 = 200
20   x  1 = 20
----------------
total:     9720
```

Does anybody have an idea how to do it?

Comment: Please read some basic C books before asking beginners questions!

Comment: I've made your question a bit less aggravating-looking (please bother with proper formatting, spelling, and capitalization).  However, you may not get many good responses if you don't show what you've already tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add an `if` statement and don't print what you don't want:

```
for(int i=0;money != 0 && i < 6; i++){

    y[i] = ( money - (money % x[i]) )/x[i];
    money = (money % x[i]);

    if(y[i] != 0)
        printf("%10d  x  %d  =  %5d \n", x[i], y[i], (x[i] * y[i]));

}
```